# How should I re-write this so I don't get a warning?

Tags: android, math

I have been updating my Android apps from Android 2.1 to 2.2 and now I keep getting this error:

```
Use java.lang.Math#sqrt instead of android.util.FloatMath#sqrt() since it is faster as of API 8
```

here are the few lines of code:

```
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
  float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
  float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
  return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

Comment: Err, use `Math.sqrt()`?  What's the actual question?

Comment: just an fyi, the # symbol in a javadoc or error like this is the equivalient of dot notation in code, so Math#sqrt is Math.sqrt in code

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as thus:

```
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return java.lang.Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

Comment: Or just cast the returend result to `(float)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to point out that in many cases it is a good idea to follow the tips provided by LINT. So in your case, the advice is quite clear, and the reason provided is self explanatory.

"Should" you rewrite it? That depends on what your code is used for. If this is something hobby based, then probably not worth it. If this is production code, I would do the rewrite.

To add to that, the more warnings that a project contains, the harder it will be to find the important / dangerous warnings. It is often considered good practice to minimise the warnings in a project. That way when something new pops up, it is easier to figure out if it is a bad one that really needs fixing.